# Image rotating animation speeds up while switching between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have an app where there's an `UIImageView` that's being rotated clockwise using `UIView.animate` like so:

```
func startAnimation(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 6)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
    })
    { finished in
        self.startAnimation(targetView: targetView, duration: duration)
    }
}
```

This function is called in `viewDidApear()` only (main reason for that is because I have 2 more `UIViewControllers` that the user can go back and forth with.

I also have a `stopAnimation()` function that is called in `viewWillDisappear()`. Main goal is to stop the animation when the user is being presented with another view controller.

```
func stopAnimation()
{
    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

**Goal:** The animation should be infinite while the user stays on the same view controller, but when they switch to another, the animation should stop and when they go back to that view controller the animation should start again with the same constant velocity.

**Problem:** For some reason each time you switch between another view controller and the view controller that has that animation, the animation is being sped up. I'm not sure what's causing that.

EDIT: Additional code as requested:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startAnimation(targetView: logo)

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call startAnimation?

Comment: I've added that to my post. Please take a look at the update

Comment: First at all I would suggest you to run your animation with options repeat, so you don't need to start it back when it finishes. Pass your options like this: options: [.curveLinear, .repeat]. I haven't tested if this will fix your problem, so you can test it maybe.

Comment: I've tested that before posting the question actually. The problem is that once the cycle of the animation is done, it makes this weird movement to the left with maybe couple of pixels or so. I cannot figure out why its making that movement. If I can, then I won't really need to start it over once its finishing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to reset the transform every time before you start animating. Otherwise it may well already be half way towards the end of the rotation. Hence taking a shorter time or further away = longer time. Also use .repeat instead of recursion.

```
func startAnimation(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 6)
{
    targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(0.0))

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {
        targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
    })
}
```